# why does spring cloud stream's @InboundChannelAdapter accept no parameters?

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-integration, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I'm trying to use spring cloud stream to send and receive messages on kafka. The examples for this use a simple example of using time stamps as the messages. I'm trying to go just one step further into a real world application when I ran into this blocker on the [InboundChannelAdapter docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/index.html?org/springframework/integration/annotation/InboundChannelAdapter.html):

"A method annotated with @InboundChannelAdapter can't accept any parameters"

I was trying to use it like so:

```
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = ChannelManager.OUTPUT)
public EventCreated createCustomerEvent(String customerId, String thingId) {
    return new EventCreated(customerId, thingId);
}
```

What usage am I missing? I imagine that when you want to create an event, you have some data that you want to use for that event, and so you would normally pass that data in via parameters. But "A method annotated with @InboundChannelAdapter can't accept any parameters". So how are you supposed to use this?

I understand that @InboundChannelAdapter comes from spring-integration, which spring-cloud-stream extends, and so spring-integration may have a different context in which this makes sense. But it seems un-intuitive to me (as does using an _INBOUND_ChannelAdapter for an output/producer/source)

Answer (score 2):

Well, first of all the `@InboundChannelAdapter` is defined exactly in [Spring Integration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/configuration.html#annotations) and Spring Cloud Stream doesn't extend it. That's false. Not sure where you have picked up that info...

This annotation builds something like `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` which provides a poller based on the scheduler and calls periodically a `MessageSource.receive()`. Since there is no any context and end-user can't effect that poller's behavior with his own arguments, the requirement for empty method parameters is obvious.

This `@InboundChannelAdapter` is a beginning of the flow and it is *active*. It does its logic on background without your events.

If you would like to call some method with parameters and trigger with that some flow, you should consider to use `@MessagingGateway`: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#messaging-gateway-annotation

Comment: Where did I say anything about extending InboundChannelAdapter? What did I say or imply about it that you are saying is false?
The polling is also confusing for a source. Why would I be polling on something I am producing?
It just seems like a bad usage in spring cloud stream of these patterns from spring integration. I think I will just look at spring kafka or confluent.

Answer (score 1):

How are you expecting to call that method? I think there was a miscommunication with your statement "stream extends integration" and Artem probably understood that we extend `@InboundChannelAdatper`

So, if you are actively calling this method, as it appears since you do have arguments that are passed to it, why not just using your source channel to send the data?

Usually sources do not require arguments as they are either push like the twitter stream that taps on twitter, listen for events and pushes them to the source channel, or they are polled, in which case, they are invoked on an interval defined via a poller.

As Artem pointed, if your intention is to call this method from your business flow, and deal with the return while triggering a message flow, then check his link from the docs.

Comment: Is there an example of "using the source channel to send the data"? I've been using the Reference docs and don't see a clear one. Are we supposed to extend the Source interface to do this? Or is the example in section 3.1.3 on Accessing Bound Channels?

Comment: Yes, you can find it here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Ditmars.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_accessing_bound_channels. All you need to do is inject your Source channel and then invoke the send() method of the MessageChannel

Comment: Do you know of any examples of how to configure this in application.yml? Especially with kafka topics? This is another piece I can't find examples of. For example, I have a Processor with an @Output("is-this-my-kafka-topic-name") and am wondering how to connect it all with the magic application.yml properties

Comment: The docs? You should have enough understanding if you go through sections 1-6. It explains the programming model, and configuration options. What magic are you talking about? The name of your channel is reflected on `spring.cloud.bindings.<channelName>` from this base property value you can control things such as name of the destination (by default will be the channel name), contentType, and binder specific properties

Comment: Thanks. I tried that. I'm doing both sending and receiving messages, so I have a Processor, with customNames for the channels, but spring bean factory is having a hard time finding the @Qualified beans. I created another question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45358914/why-cant-spring-find-the-source-bean-channel-created-by-spring-cloud-stream